# Solutions of the quadratic congruence $x^2\equiv 35\pmod{67}$

Tags: number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues

What are the solutions of the following quadratic congruence?

$$x^2\equiv 35\pmod{67}$$

I can prove that the congruence has a solution but I can't find the solutions.

Comment: Just from testing a couple values, $169\equiv35\pmod{67}$.  I assume there is a better way of solving it though.

Comment: @Mike: My answer is one way for primes of the form $4k+3$. For primes of the form $4k+1$ there is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

A particular solution is $x^2 = 2*67 + 35 = 169$, giving $x = \pm 13$.

Hence the general solution is $x \equiv 13 \pmod {67}$ or $x \equiv -13 \equiv 54 \pmod{67}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given prime $p = 4k+3$ and $a,x$ such that $x^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$:

$(a^{k+1})^2 \equiv x^{4k+4} \equiv x^2 \equiv a \pmod{p}$.

Therefore $(35^{17})^2 \equiv 35 \pmod{67}$.

$35^{17} \equiv 54 \pmod{67}$.